# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.250.154.115:27017

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

While I'm working on my school project, This error just randomly showed up.

Error connecting to MongoDB: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.250.154.115:27017

even in the compass is not working, I tried to run my other project that has a MongoDB connection and they are all inputting the same error

I tried to search it before asking this. this is what I already did

-terminating cluster and creating new

-check the IP address in network access and it's in public

-restart my laptop

-creating a new MongoDB account

-doubled check the URI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sN2t.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUWcy.png)

is there having the same problem as me that is being solved?
btw I'm using mern stack

Comment: please post code and not pictures of code.

Comment: timeout means, that machine is not reachable from your network or there is no service listening on that port. as we don't know anything about your setup it's quite hard to help

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

In order to better understand these options, I strongly recommend you to read the Mongoose documentation about the deprecation warnings.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/deprecations.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.