# MongoDB: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.7.44.13:27017

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

I've been trying to the most basics of things, yet it still gives me crap.

All i'm trying to do is connect my mongodb compass to my mongodb atlas, i presumed atleast i'll get an error when connecting spring boot to mongodb, but i'm getting it at the start.

This was supposed to be the uri link;
[enter image description here][https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoZFs.png]

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PdEmeopJVQ)

So when i try to connect thru compass using atlas i get this

[image]

I'm also getting the same error when I connect using mongosh

[image]

I checked other questions like [these] ([MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.250.154.115:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092673/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-etimedout-13-250-154-11527017)) but they have no answers.

I was expecting it to connect smoothly, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to see if, for some reason, your IP is not whitelisted. Go to `Security > Network Access` and then check to see if your IP (current IP) is there and it's active.

[image: network tab]

I just created a Free Tier on Atlas and was able to connect using visual studio extension. `mongodb+srv://testuser:XPTO@cluster0.XPTO.mongodb.net/test`

Is this a test? Can you delete and create another one without losing data? I recommend trying that as well.

[image: proof of connection]

Comment: Tried, got the same error [image](https://imgur.com/a/DcvUniQ)

Comment: My ip address is is mentioned already, and hence that does not seem the issue. [image](https://imgur.com/a/WbtX80q)

Comment: Oh no, I meant checking the IPs and creating a different cluster. One of the steps is security settings. The error is usually permissions, being cloud most of the time IPs are blocked or something.

Comment: Hmm. Let's Rubber duck this thing then, have you tried creating a different user with simpler username/pwd? Something like "mytestuser@mytestpassword"? You could also check to see if its related to your network itself, I had some members of my team with issues connecting on a few servers, they had to use 4G because wifi wasn't working.

Are you using any sort of VPN?

Comment: tried all the things you mentioned but none worked, getting the same error